# Replace array element in fp-ts

Tags: fp-ts

How would I go about replacing the string `cat` with `dog` in the array below?

My example below is a mix of standard js and fp-ts, was curious if there was something in the Array module that would solve this.

```js
const animals = ['monkey','cat','lion']

const result = pipe(
    animals,
    A.findIndex((animal)=> animal === 'cat'),
    O.matchW(
      () => animals,
      (index) => //Looking for fp-ts solution here
    )
  )

//Expected Result: ['monkey','dog','lion']
```

Comment: Do you want to replace only the first occurrence or all of them?

Comment: @DenisFrezzato This is for replacing first occurrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `A.updateAt`. Notice I also wrap `O.none` condition result so they both conditions return an `Option<string[]>`

```
O.matchW(
  () => O.some(animals),
  (index) => A.updateAt(index, 'dog')(animals)
)
```

Comment: `Option<Error,string[]>` this is wrong, `Option` has one type variable.

Comment: @DenisFrezzato You're completely right, edited the post correctly.